# What is the modulus of $a^{iy}$ when y is real?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

Consider some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. We know that for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$, $|e^{i\theta}|=1$. But what about the modulus of $a^{i\theta}$ in general? I reasoned that if $a>0$, then
\begin{align*}|a^{i\theta}|&=|(e^{\ln(a)})^{i\theta}|\\
&=|e^{i\theta\ln(a)}|\\
&=1.
\end{align*}

But the logarithm is not defined for $a<0$ so the above procedure does not work. Instead what I try is the following:
\begin{align*} |a^{i\theta}|&=|(-1)^{i\theta}|a|^{i\theta}|\\
&=|(-1)^{i\theta}|\cdot|(e^{\ln|a|})^{i\theta}|\\
&=|(-1)^{i\theta}|\cdot|e^{i\theta\ln|a|}|\\
&=|(-1)^{i\theta}|.
\end{align*}

Here is where things go wrong. It is true that $-1=e^{(2n+1)\pi i}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If we then substitute this in for any choice of $n$, we have
$$|a^{i\theta}|=e^{-(2n+1)\pi\theta},$$
which would imply $a^{i\theta}=0$ (let $n\to\infty$). Is any of this correct? Where does the $a<0$ case break down?

Edit: For context, I am trying to bound the function $|a^z|$ in order to apply Ramanujan's Master Theorem to the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\ dx$. I'm aware it can be much more easily solved.

Comment: No, $a^{iy}$ is a multivalued function. The limit of the values doesn’t give you a value.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see, so I need to choose a branch before I consider taking the modulus.

Comment: Right. Even $a>0$ has multiple branches for $a^z,$ it’s just that we have an obvious branch to choose for $\log a.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Just to be sure, the branches correspond to a choice of $n$ in the following definition: $a^{i\theta}:=e^{i\theta\ln(a)+2\pi ni}$. Is that correct? It looks like the modulus is 1 regardless of the branch chosen in the $a>0$ case if that's right.

Comment: No, the branches are $a=e^{\log a +2i n\pi}$ so $$a^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta\log a-2\theta n\pi}$$ So these branches change the modulus, too.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Glad I asked. So the $a<0$ case involves a choice of two integers $m,n$ since $-|a|=e^{(2m+1)\pi i}e^{\ln|a|+2\pi ni}$? In which case, we have
$$a^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta\ln|a|}e^{-(2(m+n)+1)\pi\theta}.$$

Comment: It’s only one integer. The two can be combined into one.